# Параллельный доступ Flask application

Tags: python, flask

Имеется веб приложение, которое реализовано на `Flask`. Вопрос заключается в следующем. 
Идея такая - два разных пользователя загружают например списки товаров. После этого пользователь А изменяет товар, и пользователь Б тоже изменяет этот же товар.
Система должна определить, Что товар был уже изменен и второй пользователь перезаписывает информацию, внесенную первым. Это может выглядеть как сообщение пользователю Б в котором написано что он перезаписывает.
Сама система работает с базой данных приложения, используя `SQLAlchemy`. 
Сам Flask по умолчанию обрабатывает запросы последовательно, поэтому вопрос, что нужно сделать, чтобы реализовать посыл сообщения пользователю Б.
Уже день ищу в интернете, ничего интересного не вижу.

Answer (score 3):

[Оптимистическая блокировка](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/versioning.html) спасёт отца русской демократии. Это самое простое решение, требующее незначительных доработок:

1. Добавляете в модель поле, хранящее версию данных;
2. Добавляете обработку исключения `StaleDataError` в обработчик сохраняющий товар;
3. Добавляете шаблон с формой для разрешения конфликта.

Answer (score 2):

Обмен сообщениями в реальном времени или отправку сообщения пользователю о каком-то изменении можно реализовать с помощью `SocketIO` - https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio

Есть интеграция с `Flask`